# Copying files from paths in text file with shutil.copy2

Tags: python-3.x, input, shutil

I'm slowly working my way towards a script for copying files after a list of UNC paths.

```
import shutil
src = input("File to read lines from: ") # Using a text file with one UNC path per line
dst = input("Destination folder: ") # UNC path, with write rights
source = open(src, "r")
while True:
    lineread = source.readline()
    shutil.copy2(lineread, dst)
    if len(lineread) == 0:
        break

    print(lineread, end="")

source.close()
```

I end up with the error

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '\\\\..\\..\\..\\filename\n'
```

Obviously, the lines aren't read as raw_strings.

I tried changing

```
source = open(src, "r")
```

to

```
source = open(src, 'r')
```

And then I get

```
TypeError: invalid file: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='filename.txt' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>
```

The script below lists the lines properly.

```
mynewhandle = open("test.txt", "r")
while True:                            # Keep reading forever
    theline = mynewhandle.readline()   # Try to read next line
    if len(theline) == 0:              # If there are no more lines
        break                          #     leave the loop

    # Now process the line we've just read
    print(theline, end="")

mynewhandle.close()
```

It should be so simple, I'm going code blind..

Comment: Yeah, it was a poor description, what I meant was that \\\\..\\ was supposed to indicate a server.. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things to be improved. The following is fine:

```
import shutil
src = input("File to read lines from: ") # Using a text file with one UNC path per line
dst = input("Destination folder: ") # UNC path, with write rights
```

When opening a text file, I recommend to get used to the `with` construct. When reading lines from a text file, use the `for` loop. As eryksun wrote, the lines are returned including the newline. Use as descriptive identifiers as possible:

```
with open(src) as file_with_filenames:
    for fname in file_with_filenames:
        fname = fname.rstrip()
        shutil.copy2(fname, dst)
        print(fname)
```

The `with` will close the object for you. Think about the `for` loop as about *do loop through all the elements of the object*. The elements of a text file are the lines as strings (including newline if it is there -- need not to be at the last line).

Try if that works for you (with UNC paths). It is normal to see the backslashes doubled in the error messages. It is just the way how to represent the bacslash as an escape sequence. You can use normal slashes instead, but I am not sure if it is OK also for the first parts of a UNC path.

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I still got this error though:

`TypeError: invalid file: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='filename.txt' mode='r' encoding='cp1252'>`

This was due to the file already being open, so I changed `with open(src)` to `with src`, which worked.

Comment: Was the `filename.txt` the one that contained the list of files? Or who opened it? Using `with src` does not make much sense.

Comment: Ahhh, right, I didn't see you removed the `open`up at the `src`.

Yes, filename,txt, contained the list of files.

Comment: Or you use `open()`/`close()` and no `with`, or you use `with open(...)` without the `close` that is done automatically. The main reason is that one do not forget to place the `close` correctly and to think about all situations that may lead to not calling the explicit `close`. Practically, the main reason is that you will not forget to write the `close` as the pair operation for the `open`. (Think also about the situation when the code is modified later and the `close` is removed accidentally.